# a+= b does not give correct results of 'a' inside a array.map() Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an issue where I'm unable to render any contents written within the arrya.map(). Forex:

```
var array = [4,6,7,8,9];
var newVal= 0;
```

I do:

```
array.map(function(x){
    return [ '<span class="xClass">',
              x, // the xClass shows up with no value in the DOM, however I see the value when debugging
            '</span>'].join('');
});
```

Hence I tried something like:

```
array.map(function(x){
newVal += x; 
});

return [
'<span class="xClass">',
              newVal,
'</span>'
].join('');
```

but the above gives me weired values for `newVal` numbers altogether, not sure how the calc is made. Is there a way where we could stored the mapped values and then use them later inside a return ()?
this is the o/p I was hoping to get:

```
<span>4</span>
<span>6</span>
<span>7</span>
<span>8</span>
<span>9</span>
```

Comment: Why are you using `map` if you don’t return anything? Where’s `newVal` defined? What result do you get and what do you expect? Why don’t you use `reduce` instead: `array.reduce((sum, value) => sum + value, 0)`?

Comment: Your original code should work just fine. What exactly do you mean by "*the xClass shows up with no value in the DOM*"? Can you show us the code that actually puts this thing into the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I don't misunderstood your question then you need something like this.

1. Wrap the code into a `function` e.g `getSpanWithValue()`
2. Initialize the newVal with some value e.g `newVal = 0`
3. Return the mapped result in this case return `newVal` and assign it to a variable e.g `mapped_result`
4. Concatenate the `mapped_result` between `<span>` using `+`.

```js
function getSpanWithValue() {
  var array = [4, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  var newVal = 0;
  var mapped_result = array.map(function(x) {
    newVal += x;
    return newVal;
  });

  return ['<span class="xClass">' + mapped_result + '</span>'].join('');
}

console.log(getSpanWithValue())
```

**For Multiple** `<span>`

```js
function getSpanWithValue() {
  var array = [4, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  var newVal = 0;
  var mapped_result = array.map(function(x) {
    newVal += x;
    return ['<span class="xClass">' + newVal + '</span>'];
  });

  return mapped_result.join(' ');
}

console.log(getSpanWithValue())
```